# Suddenly lost my wifi card?

Tags: wireless

I have a bcm4312 wireless card (Dell Inspiron 1545). I have suddenly lost my wireless card! Well, not literally, its still in my laptop, but Ubuntu denies all knowledge of it even existing! I've tried `lspci` - not there, I've `grep`'d the `lspci` to be sure I'm not just crazy, it's not there.

Its also not acknowledged as being there in Additional Drivers - "no proprietary drivers are in use on this system".

This is very frustrating! Any ideas? I'm completely stumped.

On a semi-related note, if I cant get it working, is there a wireless mini card that is open source that works with the dell inspiron 1545?

Comment: I would double check to make sure you have disabled the hardware switch, on my laptop it is an actual switch, but I have seen some that are buttons, or even keys on the keyboard.

Comment: I have the same chip in my AAO D260 - it dissapeared after I upgraded compat wireless drivers. Try to install some older ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check that removing and reinserting brings the card to life.

I would boot from a live USB/CD and check `lspci`.  If it still reports that the card is not available then the card has most probably died.

I've just checked ebay - lots of dell inspiron 1545 mini cards for less than $10.  Perhaps better to stick with a card that you know definitely works in your laptop model.